# Почему в MS SQL Server создается новая схема БД при использовании SELECT INTO?

Tags: sql-server

Всем доброго дня. С MS SQL Server раньше не работал, недавно пришлось столкнуться по работе, необходимо выполнить одну служебную задачу, но наткнулся на некую странность, был бы очень признателен знатокам за ответ почему так происходит или совет, где про это почитать. Уверен что я просто чего-то не понимаю.

**Описание:**

Установлен **MS SQL Server 2012**. Имеется база данных предположим называется **Сompany**. В базе данных имеется одна схема **dbo**, все таблицы базы данных принадлежат этой схеме, например:

**dbo.People**

**dbo.Products**

**dbo.Сars**

и т.д.

Открываю **SQL Management Studio** и подключаюсь к серверу СУБД используя доменную авторизацию, например **CORP\Ivanov**.

Далее если выполнить создание таблицы с помощью команды **CREATE TABLE**:

```
CREATE TABLE departaments;
```

то все хорошо, создается таблица привязанная к схеме **dbo**:

**dbo.departaments**

Но если выполнить создание таблицы с помощью **SELECT INTO**:

```
SELECT * INTO departaments FROM departaments_regions;
```

то таблица создается и появляется новая схема, имя которой совпадает с доменным именем **CORP\Ivanov**, т.е. таблица представлена в дереве объектов как:

**CORP\Ivanov.departaments**

**Вопрос:**

С чем связано такое поведение?

**Примечание:**

Я в курсе, что если указать схему dbo при создании таблицы, то таблица создается в этой схеме:

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.departaments FROM departaments_regions;
```

Но интересует именно вариант без ее указания.

Comment: вы отметили ответ как верный. проблема была в прописанной default_schema? если да, то почему у вас `create table departaments` создавало таблицу в dbo, ведь она тоже должна была использовать схему пользователя?

Comment: Посмотрел в системном представлении sys.database_principals, действительно схема по умолчанию для пользователя под которым я подключался совпадает с доменным именем. То, что CREATE TABLE создает таблицу в схеме dbo, меня тоже удивило, но не стал расспрашивать, так как списал это на особенность SQL Server и моя проблема была решена, так как у пользователя под которым будет выполняться скрипт в живой базе установлена схема по умолчанию dbo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У каждого пользователя БД есть схема по умолчанию, куда попадают таблицы, которые он создает без указания схемы.

По умолчанию эта схема по умолчанию совпадает с именем пользователя (отголосок тех времен, когда "имя пользователя" и "схема" были синонимами).

Comment: если это из-за default_schema, то почему `CREATE TABLE departaments` создает в dbo? Просто create table ведь тоже использует default_schema пользователя.